# How to recover crashed Symfony App due to PHP error? PHP 5.3.1 / Apache 2.2.14

Tags: php, apache, symfony-1.4

I am getting this strange error on PHP 5.3.1 on Apache 2.2.14. I went thru the forums and most suspect it is a PHP-issue memory-leak issue. WHile I upgrade PHP, I wanted to know if there is a way for the server to recover - to be restarted programatically. Currently, I have to manually start-stop Apaache

```
Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in D:\xampp_ext\xampp\htdocs\soki\test.soki.com\symfony\lib\autoload\sfCoreAutoload.class.php on line 38

Warning: require(/config/sfProjectConfiguration.class.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp_ext\xampp\htdocs\soki\test.soki.com\symfony\lib\autoload\sfCoreAutoload.class.php on line 99

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/config/sfProjectConfiguration.class.php' (include_path='.;d:\xampp_ext\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp_ext\xampp\htdocs\soki\test.soki.com\symfony\lib\autoload\sfCoreAutoload.class.php on line 99
```

I'm using PHP 5.3.1 on Apache 2.2.14[image]

Comment: From your question it's not clear that apache crashes. How do you know apache crashed?

Comment: Do you have anythign in your apache logs?

Comment: Seems like there is an error in your PHP application, not that Apache crashed...

Comment: Those errors are given by PHP, not by Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read jillions of blog posts about the error, and my best option was to upgrade to PHP 5.3 and that resolved the problem. It was definitely due to a memory leak somewhere that was preventing additional files to be loaded

Answer (score 1):

PHP is run by Apache, so if Apache has indeed crashed, you can't easily use PHP to start Apache again **unless PHP is being called by some other program besides Apache** (example: running PHP as a cron job/scheduled task by calling PHP.exe [script.php] directly).

I'm assuming by the path in your error message that you're using a Windows environment (obviously). You don't want a script or program in the background starting Apache over and over if the process isn't running; that's messy. You *could* but that is nowhere near ideal.

How do you even know Apache is crashing? The errors you provided are errors from PHP, not Apache. If you refresh the page and still see errors (or anything besides a Connection Failure/Forcefully rejected/etc.) then Apache is still running.

- Double-check that Apache is indeed no longer running
- Check error logs in Apache's logs folder
- Report back with your findings

Comment: Thanks Daniel, you are right, Apache is still running as I see the same page over and over again. But if I manually restart the server, everything is back to normal. So I had assumed Apache went down, my bad! Any suggestions?

Comment: Back to normal? Do you mean after stopping & re-starting Apache, the errors go away and then come back? I'm not clear on what is happening. I'm also not familiar with the Symfony framework. I would start a new question now that you know it isn't Apache and mention Symfony framework and post your errors as well as when they occur and when they do not.

Comment: Well I did add the Symfony1.4 tag. Here's a summary of what's happening: For a particular request (specific module/action call), I get this error & every request after that (for other modules as well) give me this error. Apache logs say nothing. But it seems SYmfony is crashing! And there is nothing in the SF logs either. I fixed the issue by upgrading PHP - most posts about the same error suggest this & it worked! thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using mod_php requires to work with the Apache prefork worker model. There is a configuration setting you can use to implement a work-around:

With the [MaxRequestsPerChild](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestsperchild) directive you can set a number of requests that will be processed before child processes will be recycled. **Workaround:** Put it to a low value, so that Apache will recycle it's children more often.

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       2
MinSpareServers    3
MaxSpareServers    3
ServerLimit       30
MaxClients        30
MaxRequestsPerChild  200
</IfModule>
```

Please keep in mind that this is only a dirty hack and not a serious solution of your problem.